# Apache and MySQL installation on VPS

Tags: mysql, apache, configuration, hosting, vps

Is there any difference (or preference) between two schemes:

1. Apache & MySQL are installed on the same VPS (4Gb RAM, 2 CPU Cores) and each of them configured for 2GB RAM,
2. Apache and MySQL installed on separate VPS (2Gb RAM, 1 CPU Core).

Thank you.

Comment: You will find two instances easier to diagnose performance problems. Also two instances makes it easier to add a second web server and use the same backend without too much complication or asymmetry. Single instance provides the ability to push a bit more ram to mysql and a little less to Apache. Suggest https://dba.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/ next time as this isn't really a programming question which is what the focus of SO is for.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment about dba.stackexchange.com is noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to go for separate vps server

Following are the reason

1) can boost performance, u can balance the load equally

2) easier to set up replication if you have separate standalone DB server

3) easier to trouble shoot if there is a problem either in apache or mysql

4) normally if you have separate DB instance, you will allocate 80% of your RAM memory to Myisam or Innodb engine for better concurrency. If both kept in same vps, u will have to sacrifice concurrency, scalability